# sqlplus statement from command line

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to do something like this?

`$ sqlplus -s user/pass "select 1 from dual"`
or
`$ echo "select 1 from dual" | sqlplus -s user/pass`

I know I can put `select 1 from dual` in a file and do this:
`$ sqlplus -s user/pass @myFile.sql`

but I'm wondering if it's actually necessary to create a file just to satisfy sqlplus

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638705/how-can-i-issue-a-single-command-from-the-command-line-through-sql-plus

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just be aware that on Unix/Linux your username/password can be seen by anyone that can run "ps -ef" command if you place it directly on the command line . Could be a big security issue (or turn into a big security issue).

I usually recommend creating a file or using here document so you can protect the username/password from being viewed with "ps -ef" command in Unix/Linux. If the username/password is contained in a script file or sql file you can protect using appropriate user/group read permissions. Then you can keep the user/pass inside the file like this in a shell script:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect user/pass
select blah;
quit
EOF
```

Comment: not always true, depending on Oracle version and OS, but probably a good standard to follow

Comment: too bad heredoc's aren't easy in DOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch

Comment: What wonders me is why commandline leaking is not simply tackeled in the sql client program itself, as that would be quite trivial to do: in the main() function, copy the commandline args to a new variable, and overwrite the old args/argv[], and no commandline is visible (or - just for a fraction of a millisecond perhaps) - why doesn't oracle implement that solution?

Comment: @RobHeusdens because it's not Oracle's problem? Why should Oracle assume that users _shouldn't_ see what they expect to see?

Comment: @DavidMann is this supposed to be this? 

`sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect username/password@database_name
select 1 from dual;
quit
EOF`

Not sure where to put the database name.

Answer (score 52):

I'm able to execute your exact query by just making sure there is a semicolon at the end of my select statement. (Output is actual, connection params removed.)

```
echo "select 1 from dual;" | sqlplus -s username/password@host:1521/service
```

Output:

```
         1
----------
         1
```

Note that is should matter but this is running on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Oracle 11g.

Comment: +1, but be aware that if you're doing anything moderately complicated in SQL*Plus you'll usually be making a few SET directives and this will get messy if you're looking to have a one-line command.

Comment: +1 Finally, the answer!  Adding the semi-colon to the end of the query!  You actually can run sqlplus, log in, and then run the commands - you don't have to pipe in the credentials. My problem was the commands weren't running - the line numbers just kept incrementing! Now I know how to get them to run -- just add a semi-colon!  Thanks!

Comment: +1 Nice!  I used this for a `desc table_name;` command and was getting unknown command errors, but removed the quotes and it worked.  `echo desc table_name; | sqlplus uid/pwd@host`

Comment: The quotes produce an Oracle "SP2-0734: unknown command beginning ""select 1 ..." error for me on Windows.  Removing them works for me.

Comment: works for docker as well: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash -c "echo 'select table_name from user_tables;' | sqlplus username/password@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB";`. Lesson is dont forget `;` in statement to execute

Comment: Works like a charm in debian and linux distro. Thanks for sharing. Quick test example.

Comment: @GrantLammi can the password be seen like David Mann mentioned?

Answer (score 32):

My version

```
$ sqlplus -s username/password@host:port/service <<< "select 1 from dual;"


         1
----------
         1
```

EDIT:

For multiline you can use this

```
$ echo -e "select 1 from dual; \n select 2 from dual;" | sqlplus -s username/password@host:port/service


         1
----------
         1


         2
----------
         2
```

Comment: and how can we use statement stored in a variable in first version with <<<? I got the error.

Answer (score 9):

I assume this is *nix?

Use "here document":

```
sqlplus -s user/pass <<+EOF
select 1 from dual;
+EOF
```

EDIT: I should have tried your second example. It works, too (even in Windows, sans ticks):

```
$ echo 'select 1 from dual;'|sqlplus -s user/pw

         1
----------
         1


$
```

Answer (score 4):

For windows version you can try below. remove double quotes (")

```
echo select 1 from dual; | sqlplus -s username/password@service
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the one I needed.