# Is it possible to pass a single query to SQLplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I regularly need to run a single query on some table in one of my DBs and I would rather not have to create a file and call it as a script and everything if I don't have to.

I would like to be able to send the query directly to sqlplus as a string like this perhaps

```
sqlplus user/pass@hostname:port/service "select * from table"
```

instead of having to create a file that holds only that one query and call it with

```
sqlplus user/pass@hostname:port/service @filename
```

does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlplus statement from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639704/sqlplus-statement-from-command-line)

Comment: If it's the same query every time, why would you _not_ want to keep the query in .sql file?  And if it is a different query each time, what's wrong with simply starting sqlplus then entering the query at sql prompt?  Either way, what do you think you are accomplishing by putting the query on the same command line that is used to launch sqlplus?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mathguy answer, with `linux shells`,
you can use the operator `here-string` like this:

```
sqlplus user/pass@hostname:port/service <<< 'select * from table;'
```

Don't forget the semi-colon at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `sqlplus` command doesn't accept a SQL statement (as a string) as a command-line parameter. You can run `sqlplus` either interactively or in batch (giving a `.sql` file as input).

However, you can do something like what you are asking, using operating system facilities. I don't know how this might work in Windows, but in Unix/Linux you can use a `here document`. Something like this: (I masked my password and my machine name for privacy, but otherwise it's a screenshot showing the command and its output)

```
[oracle@******** ~]$ sqlplus mathguy/********@orclpdb <<EOF
> select empno, ename, sal
> from   scott.emp
> where  deptno = 30;
> EOF

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Mar 26 15:15:30 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Mar 26 2021 15:14:40 -07:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>   2    3  
     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN            1600
      7521 WARD             1250
      7654 MARTIN           1250
      7698 BLAKE            2850
      7844 TURNER           1500
      7900 JAMES             950

6 rows selected.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0
   - 64bit Production
[oracle@******** ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Never ever enter your credentials next to `sqlplus` command but use `/nolog` option through a variable assignment in order to unveil them whenever `ps` command issued by the others such as

```
rec=$(sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
conn un/pwd@mydb
set pages 1001
set linesize 500
set feedback off
SELECT * FROM tab;
exit
EOF
)
echo $rec
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Windows version:

```
echo select 1 from dual; | sqlplus -s username/password@service
```

You can use this to implement e.g. a Docker Healthcheck in a Powershell script:

```
$chekdbsql = "`nselect 1 from dual;"
$chkdb = ""
$chkdb = ($chekdbsql | cmd /c "sqlplus username/password@service")
if ($chkdb.Contains("OPEN") -eq 'True'){
    exit 0
}
else {
    exit 1
}
```