# Running direct SQL statements using a batch file

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

How can I run SQL statements in a batch file, without reading the statement in a text file?

Comment: Follow this:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638705/how-can-i-issue-a-single-command-from-the-command-line-through-sql-plus/639373#639373>

Comment: For sqlplus from windows cmd prompt you are limited to piping in the text: something like: echo select * from emp; | sqlplus user/password

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD db_name -e "SELECT whatever FROM table ..."
```