# How to execute a oracle procedure from shell

Tags: oracle, cygwin

I have a stored procedure in oracle i want to call that procedure from cygwin. This is the  procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings
AS
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!');
 END;
```

i am doing this

```
sqlplus -s system@orcl/oracle10g<<END
execute greetings();
commit;
exit;
END
```

Comment: when i am doing sh test(it is the name of the vi editor file where i write this codes)it shows PLS-00201: identifier 'GREETINGS' must be declared

Answer (score 2):

Connect Oracle using SqlPlus, then run the procedure like this:

```
execute package_name.procedure_name (parameters...)
```

If you want to call sqlplus from within Windows shell:

```
@echo execute some_procedure | sqlplus username/password@databasename
```

(See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638705/how-can-i-issue-a-single-command-from-the-command-line-through-sql-plus) )

On Unix, try this:

```
echo "execute <some_procedure>" | sqlplus -s username/password@host:1521/service
```

Comment: Thanks chance but i have to call a stored procedure from shell if you do sqlplus then the shell environment will change to oracle and the procedure will run fine.But i have to retain the shell environment, and have to call a procedure

Comment: disconnected frm  oracle database

Comment: $ echo "procPrintHelloWorld" | sqlplus -s system/oracle10g@orcl:1521/orcl

Comment: this is i am doing and my procedure is  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procPrintHelloWorld
 IS
 BEGIN
  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
  
 END;
 /

Comment: you have to create that procedure first, then try to call it from your shell.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
set serveroutput on
```

before execute greetings();

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'GREETINGS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Comment: in what schema is greetings defined? either connect as the owner of greetings(and not as system ) or set the shema name befor the procedure name: `execute SCOTT.greetings();`

Answer (score 0):

sqlplus -s system/oracle10g@orcl @proc.sql this is working fine where system is my oracle username oracle10g is my pass and orcl is the localhost and the proc.sql is the file name where the procedure is stored.All we have to do is to go to specific directory from shell then execute this script

Comment: i have just find it so i posted that thanks all for helping me