# Execute SQL query in CMD

Tags: sql, batch-file, oracle11g, cmd

I need to execute a query by logging into oracle DB using command prompt, Please help me with the query

```
cd\ && D: && Cd app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN && (set ORACLE_HOME=D:\app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1) && (sqlplus / as sysdba)
```

I am able to log into db using this but i want to execute the below query in the same script

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (startup_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time
from V$instance;
```

When I add this query using `&&`, it's not working.

Comment: Check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638705/how-can-i-issue-a-single-command-from-the-command-line-through-sql-plus

Comment: Unrelated, but: `cd\ && D: && cd ...` can be combined to single statement: `cd /d d:\app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can `@echo` the SQL query into SQL*Plus:

```
cd\ && D: && Cd app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN && (set ORACLE_HOME=D:\app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1) && (@echo SELECT TO_CHAR (startup_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time FROM v$instance; | sqlplus / as sysdba)
```

Comment: Hi mureinik, Thanks for the solution, upon firing this script i got the below error "start_time was unexpected at this time"